# Screw Terminal Broken Screw Removal

Tags: screw-terminal

I have a NI DAQ and while connecting wires I tightened the screws a bit more. When I tried to unscrew, the screw head broke and came off. Now I am unable to remove the screws and use the particular pin.

Could anyone suggest how I can remove the broken head screws?

Comment: Not an EE question, of course... But I would try drilling it in few places, such that it can be driven out with a screwdriver or pliers.

Comment: Alternatively use a Dremel to cut a slot in the terminal and broken screw so you can get a screwdriver into it.

Comment: There are scads of [videos to watch on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+screw&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpwoSOmtzVAhWms1QKHZ9sBgIQ_AUICigB&biw=1472&bih=726) some of which are quite interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is assuming the *screws are completely removable from the DAQ.*

I would remove the screw using a left hand drill bit. Find one that is safely smaller than the threaded hole so you don't damage the threads, set the drill to reverse, and drill down the head of the screw. One of two things will then happen:

1. You will completely destroy the screw turning it to dust.
2. The screw will catch and become unscrewed since the bit is spinning in the reverse direction.

Either way, go slowly and carefully so you don't damage anything else.

When the screw is out, remove another undamaged screw and take it to a hardware store or a place like Fastenal and they should be able to find a replacement for you.